# Find maximum $k$ that inequality $\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^3}{ka^2+b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{k+1}$ holds

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

When I'm trying [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1777075) problem, I find it could be harder if choose a larger $k$ (in the original problem $k=13/5=2.6$):

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
> $$\frac{a^3}{ka^2+b^2}+\frac{b^3}{kb^2+c^2}+\frac{c^3}{kc^2+a^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{k+1}$$

e.g. the inequality still holds when $k=164/63=2.6032...$ (I proved it by [Successive Difference Substitution](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.4030v3.pdf), a computer-automated buffalo-way. I think it can also be proved by [CAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition) or other methods mentioned in the original thread) but doesn't hold when $k=315/121=2.6033...$ (the figure shows 3 very small negative areas).

[image: k=315/121]

I guess the critical point is just a slight above 2.60325... (still holds at $2.603250$), but I don't know if it is a rational number or irrational (or transcendental).

Comment: It's most definitely a root of some extremely hairy polynomial (with radicals allowed probably).  Much simpler question like $x^3+y^3+z^3+k(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)\geq(k+1)(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)$ turns out to have the optimal (in this case maximal) $k$ to be a root of a cubic, for example.

Comment: By *Mathematica*, the maximal $k\approx 2.603260274$ is a real root of $64\,{x}^{15}-1504\,{x}^{14}+13076\,{x}^{13}-38833\,{x}^{12}-49126\,{x}
^{11}+146301\,{x}^{10}+316414\,{x}^{9}-466451\,{x}^{8}-61696\,{x}^{7}+
1051234\,{x}^{6}+162556\,{x}^{5}+290137\,{x}^{4}+768982\,{x}^{3}+
157577\,{x}^{2}+262722\,x+258147
=0$.

Comment: @dezdichado in your question the critical point is $k^4+2k^3-5k^2-6k-23=0$ then $k=(\sqrt{13+16\sqrt{2}}-1)/2=2.4844...$.

Comment: @RiverLi can you provide the detail how you (or *Mathematica*) get the 15-degree equation?

Comment: @auntyellow Mathematica code: f[a_, b_] := 
a^5*b^2*k + a^4*b^3*k - a^4*b^2*k^2 - a^3*b^4*k + a^3*b^2*k^2 + 
a^2*b^5 - a^2*b^4*k + a^2*b^3*k^2 - a*b^4*k^2 - a^4*b*k + 
a^2*b^2*k^2 + b^5*k + a^5 - a^4*k - a^3*b^2 - a^2*b^3 - a^2*b*k^2 + 
b^4*k + a^3*k - a^2*b^2 - a*b^2*k - b^3*k + a^2*k + b^2
pos1 := a >= 0 && b >= 0
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b}, pos1, f[a, b] >= 0], Reals] (Let $c = 1$ in the original inequality and clear the denominators. For the code, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016364/inequality-a-b-c-d-subset0-1-rightarrow-sum-limits-cyca4a2b28-pr))